# How do i check multiple parameters in URL

Tags: php

http://example.com/retrieve1.php?Grade=&School=&Team=&Students=

How do i check multiple parameters in above URL ?I am using different search filters such as (Grade, School, Team, Students). So i would like to use the values of these filters from URL. I am not sure how to approach this, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: they are all inside the superglobal GET, view them all with `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: @Dagon may i know  if (isset($_GET['url']))  does the same thing ?

Comment: no as you have no key `querry` in that url. `echo $_GET['Grade']` etc will show the values

Comment: @Dagon okay understood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**URL:** http://example.com/retrieve1.php?Grade=&School=&Team=&Students=

> Two HTTP Request Methods: GET and POST
>
> Two commonly used methods for a request-response between a client and
>   server are: GET and POST.
>
> ```
> GET - Requests data from a specified resource
> POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource For your
> ```

For your url its a GET method.

You can store the url parameter value using the `GET` Method.

```
$Grade = $_GET['Grade'];
$School= $_GET['School'];
$Team= $_GET['Team'];
$Students= $_GET['Students'];
```

You can also store the url parameter value using the `REQUEST` Method.

```
$Grade = $_REQUEST['Grade'];
$School= $_REQUEST['School'];
$Team= $_REQUEST['Team'];
$Students= $_REQUEST['Students'];
```

> Note: The variables in $_REQUEST are provided to the script via the
>   GET, POST, and COOKIE input mechanisms and therefore could be modified
>   by the remote user and cannot be trusted. The presence and order of
>   variables listed in this array is defined according to the PHP
>   variables_order configuration directive.

Comment: don't use request.

Comment: @Dagon, why?? Is there any side effect??

Comment: if you know you want GET use GET, REQUEST also contains $_POST and $_COOKIE. what happens when i send post Grade and get Grade

Comment: @Dagon hmm, i just saw and add a note in my answer.

Comment: @jon, If you benefited of my answer then there is option to accept the answer, you can do it.